# Even googling not allowed ? Why?

Tags: networking, permissions, firewall, google-search

> Access has been denied 127.0.0.1!
> Access to the page:
>
> http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=F58&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=email+us&meta=&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=
>
> ... has been denied for the following reason:
>
> **Weighted phrase limit exceeded.**

---

By reading above message, you can easily understand that - it's a firewall message.
I also know that.

- The problem is "Firewall" is allowing any kind of googling.
- But when I google "email us" - above message is displayed.
- My question is why does this happen ? ( means - why googling not allowed on this words ? )
  ( Please don't tell that - contact your system administrator. )
- What does this mean - **Weighted phrase limit exceeded.** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that your administrator does not want you to google for the phrase email.

Mostly it is to prevent workers from uploading anything into the network, therefore webmailer, web2.0 services and the like are filtered out.

Weighted phrase limit exceeded seems to be a hint on the working mechanism of the filter, that has a list of buzzwords weighed with a score, if the url has one or more words of the list in it, the score is summed up. If the sum is greater than a tolerance, the url is blocked.